# auto refresh page after certain time if no activity in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

**i want auto refrersh page if there is no activity on page till 15 minutes in reactjs i have tried below solution but it is not proerly work**

```
  let inactivityTime = 0;

  function trackUserActivity() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', resetTimer);
    document.addEventListener('keypress', resetTimer);
  }
  
  function resetTimer() {
    inactivityTime = 0;
  }
  
  function refreshPageAfterInactivity() {
    trackUserActivity();
    setInterval(function() {
      inactivityTime += 1;
      if (inactivityTime > 15 * 60) { 
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    }, 1000); 
  }
  
  refreshPageAfterInactivity();
```

Comment: What does not work with your solution? I tried it in Chrome and it seems to work fine.

Comment: it will not work proper sometimes it will refresh and some time not refresh even not activity perform

Comment: Please provide more information on where this piece of code is placed inside your application. I'd also suggest to add some log output for debugging purpose to make sure there's no activity on your page and get the current value of inactivityTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use useEffect in react which help you to re-render the component .

for testing purpose, I have set a time of 1 minute.

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const InactivityRefresh = () => {
  const [inactivityTime, setInactivityTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resetTimer = () => {
      setInactivityTime(0);
    };

    const trackUserActivity = () => {
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
      document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer);

      return () => {
       
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
        document.removeEventListener("keypress", resetTimer);
      };
    };

    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setInactivityTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);
    }, 1000);

    const refreshPageAfterInactivity = () => {
      trackUserActivity();

      return () => {
       
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      };
    };

    refreshPageAfterInactivity();

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
      document.removeEventListener("keypress", resetTimer);
    };
  }, []); 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inactivityTime > 1 * 60) {
      console.log('sdfsdfsdfsd');
      window.location.reload(true);
    }
  }, [inactivityTime]);

  return <div>Your component content goes here.</div>;
};

export default InactivityRefresh;
```